# Single word for “for how long information is considered fresh”

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a single word for “for how long a piece of information is considered fresh”.

Suppose I have a piece of information, say a score of a cricket match at a particular moment in an ongoing live match. It can be considered as “stale” or “fresh” depending upon whether we have updated information available or not.

I was thinking of *validity* but somehow it doesn’t look correct to me. Validity is more like whether something is correct or incorrect.

Comment: *Freshness*, or *staleness*, or even *age* or *TTL* (*time to live*). Welcome to EL&U; requests to name a variable or data structure are explicitly off topic. Thanks.

Comment: *Current* probably.

Comment: If this is always about a game, wouldn't it just be the *Score*? And when the game is over, *Final Score*?

Answer (score 5):

You can consider,

- [Relevance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relevance)
- [Currency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/currency)
- [Shelf-life](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shelf_life)

MετάEd's suggestion of *TTL* is also a good 'un.

Comment: I think *currency* will be confusing. This use is relatively unknown comparing to "type of money".

Comment: @SF. _Currentness_ might perhaps be a less confusing variant.

Answer (score 2):

> [Topicality](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbo=u&q=topicality&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=aBcAUbq2BuGK0AXly4GIDQ&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=4588547da649677a&biw=1253&bih=886) - the attribute of being of interest at the present time;
>   *"the library had to discard books that had lost their topicality"*.

Comment: How might you apply this to the OP's example of a cricket score? Topicality at the moment is 63-1?

Comment: @spiceyokooko: The half-time score is not _topical_ now that the match is over.  But _relevant_ is probably a better fit in that context.

Comment: @Scott,spiceyokooko: Yeah, *topicality* isn't normally appropriate in the context of "intermediate" values/states that are part of a relatively short-lived single process with a defined beginning and end, where only the final values really matter. I those contexts we're not usually interested in the "superseded" values anyway - all we care about at any given moment is the ***latest*** value.

Comment: @spiceyokooko,FumbleFingers: But I believe the treatment and interpretation of my example don’t change much even if it is changed to refer to (semi-)final information: The standings at the end of last season are not _________ now that we’re a month into the new season.

Comment: @scott I don't see how *relevant* answers the OP's question regarding a constantly changing score. What describes a score that is *only* correct at the time of a page refresh? *Current* score.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Gosh, I believe that the score at 10:00:00 is still somewhat relevant at 10:00:05 or 10:00:10, or maybe even at 10:01 or 10:10.  If I know that the team I’m rooting for was 42 points ahead 10 minutes ago, I can feel somewhat confident that they’re still ahead now.  An hour later, that information has become less _relevant_, because the situation may have changed radically.  ...  P.S. I believe that you mean “that is **correct** ***only*** at the time of a page refresh”.

Comment: @scott I think our interpretation of what OP is looking for is somewhat different.

Comment: Well, OP still hasn't posted any updates to clarify exactly what he *does* mean, so we're all a bit in the dark here. But I must say that given the fact that ["validity of two years"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22validity+of+two+years%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, is perfectly normal English, I'm starting to feel the question is effectively Not Constructive, since it seems to be predicated on OP's mistaken understanding of *validity*. Plus I suspect he's just looking for a "programming" word, in which case "time to live" is probably all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[up-to-dateness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up-to-dateness)*?

> extending up to the present time : including the latest information

Answer (score 1):

Data freshness - used for talking with non IT experts.
Data staleness - used for talking with IT experts. As data really starts going stale as soon as you collect it.
Data currency - used for talking with anyone. It's about how current data is, i.e., freshness/staleness AND measure of relevance. Regarding relevance, business data model is always evolving, so not only does the data itself age but, so does its' usefulness. In other contexts "data currency" is talking about data as a currency.

Answer (score 0):

Just "up to date".  (Yes, I know, lexically is not a single word, but semantically it is.)

As an adjective: "up-to-date."

> "We do not have up-to-date information, as it has been 20 minutes.

Also, in broadcast, "latest" is used.

> And now the latest on...